# Filtering out None from the list of pd.Series / or finding out Nonetype objects in the list of pd.Series

Tags: python, pandas, list, nonetype

I'm having a problem while removing Nonetype objects in the list.
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

This is incurred when:

```
import pandas as pd
#List of pd.Series with some of the objects are None
results = [pd.Series([1,2,3,4]), None, pd.Series([2,3,4,5])]
print(list(filter(None, results)))
```

How can I filter out the Nonetype objects in the list?
I know I can do with loops, but it'll not be pythonic ways.

Comment: `pd.Series([1,2,None,4])` do you want to consider it or not as a None?

Comment: @Epsi95 I don't want to consider it as None. My datas don't include such cases.

Comment: Post a working script that demonstrates the problem. When I run your example, I get `<filter object at 0x7fddcd7fd6a0>`.

Comment: @hun what about `pd.Series([None, None,None,None])`, do you want to consider it as None?

Comment: @Epsi95 Nope. I don't want to. Thanks for asking a detail. Seems like I'm  missing quite an important context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `filter`function is `None`, python will do a truth test on each item (`bool(item)`). So, when should a `pd.Series` be `True`? Is it when all of its values are `True`? Any of the values? Maybe just when the series is not empty. The point is, there are many ways a series could be true. That's what the error message is telling you.

Since your goal is to filter out `None`, and list comprehensions are a better choice than `filter` anyway, you can just test for `None`.

```
print([value for value in results if value is not None])
```

Answer (score 2):

you are getting the error because, consider the below 2 cases

1. None
2. [None, 1, 2, 3]

Now when you compare that is anything is `None` you get the following

1. True (because None is None)
2. [True, False, False, False]

Now for the first case it is obvious that it is None
But for the second case, python is confused whether you want to consider it as None `just because there is one None` or you are okay that `there is not all None` and that is the source of the error. `any` means that you will consider it as `None` if there is at least one None and all means there should be all `None`

```py
#List of pd.Series with some of the objects are None
results = [pd.Series([1,2,3,4]), None, pd.Series([2,3,4,5])]

def is_none(x):
  try:
    return return any(x == None)
  except:
    return x is None

print(list(filter(is_none, results)))

# [0    1
# 1    2
# 2    3
# 3    4
# dtype: int64, None, 0    2
# 1    3
# 2    4
# 3    5
# dtype: int64]
```

Comment: I think OP just wants to remove the `None`. All pd.Series objects should remain.

Comment: @tdelaney oh okay, the requirement was not very clear, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the problem are the 'None' elements in your list, you can always just create another list without them and override the first list:

```py
results=[i for i in results if i is not None ].
```

This also avoids any "explicit" loops, though obviously, internally, there's a loop going on.

Comment: I have edited you answer, checking with None should be done with `is` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use a builtin python method `isinstance` to check to see if you element is an instance of `pandas.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
#List of pd.Series with some of the objects are None
results = [pd.Series([1,2,3,4]), None, pd.Series([2,3,4,5])]
[i for i in results if isinstance(i, pd.Series)]
```

OR

```
list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, pd.Series), results))
```

Output:

```
[0    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    4
 dtype: int64,
 0    2
 1    3
 2    4
 3    5
 dtype: int64]
```